# Consequence of the Yoneda lemma

Tags: category-theory, functors, yoneda-lemma

Take a functor $G:\mathbb D\to \mathbb C $, and call $Y:\mathbb D\to [\operatorname{\mathbb D,Set]}:D\mapsto\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb D}(-,D)$ the Yoneda  functor. Consider the bifunctor $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb D}(-,G-):\mathbb C \times \mathbb D\to \operatorname {Set}$, contravariant in the first  variable  and covariant in the second one. Intuitively, this  bifunctor carries the same data of the functor $YG$; if one takes another $G':\mathbb D\to \mathbb C $ such that  $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb D}(-,G'-)$ is naturally isomorphic (in both variables) to $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb D}     (-,G-)$, one basically is saying that $YG\cong YG'$ (naturally); since $Y$ is fully faithful, $G\cong G'$ (naturally). Can anyone help me to prove rigorously what I said above (in particular where I wrote *intuitively*)? In class we just said that the it is a consequence of Yoneda.

P.S. If it can be useful, this argument came up in a proof that the right adjoint of a functor is uniquely determined modulo natural isomorphisms, observing that, given $F\dashv G,G':\mathbb D \to \mathbb C$, there are natural bijections $\operatorname{Hom}(-,G-)\cong \operatorname{Hom}(F-,-)\cong \operatorname{Hom}(-,G'-).$ I even read the proof of this fact in the book of Mac Lane (it's the corollary $\operatorname{IV.1.1}$), and I understand it, but I can't use it to solve my question.

Comment: Relevant: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/profunctor - in particular the construction of the profunctor associated to a functor, which is in fact fully faithful.

Comment: I think $G,G' : \mathbb C \to \mathbb D$ instead of $G,G' : \mathbb D \to \mathbb C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard type of argument, but it is rarely spelled out. That makes it difficult for new people, it took me a while before I understood what *and the rest follows by Yoneda* means.

The crucial fact you need is that faithful functors reflect commutativity of diagrams. Of course all functors do preserve commutativity. The Yoneda embedding $Y: \mathcal D \to [\mathcal D^{op}, \mathbf {Set}]$ is fully faithful. So if for example $Ya \circ Yb = Yc \circ Yd\circ Ye$ holds in the category of functors, then it follows that $a\circ b = c\circ d\circ e$ is true in $\mathcal D$. This is because $Y$ is injective on homsets. Also fully faithful functors reflect isomorphisms.

Your functors $G$ and $G'$ should be of type $\mathcal C\to \mathcal D$. I assume you like to show that if
\begin{align}
\mathcal D(d,Gc) \cong \mathcal D(d,G'c)
\end{align}
naturally in both variables, then $G$ is naturally isomorphic to $G'$. This is the difficult direction. So assume you have a natural isomorphism as above. Then in particular
\begin{align}
 \mathcal D(-,Gc) \cong \mathcal D'(-,G'c) 
\end{align}
are naturally isomorphic for fixed $c$. By Yoneda's lemma any such isomorphism is of the form $\mathcal D(-,\alpha_c)$ for a unique morphism $\alpha_c: Gc \to Gc'$ in $\mathcal D$. The family of morphisms $\alpha_c$ we obtain this way assemble into the natural isomorphism $\alpha: G\Rightarrow G'$ we are trying to construct. We need to show that $\alpha_c$ are isomorphisms and that $\alpha$ is natural. Note that $Y\alpha_c = \mathcal D(-,\alpha_c)$ is an isomorphism by construction. The Yoneda embedding is fully faithful and therefor reflects isomorphisms. It follows that each $\alpha_c$ is an isomorphism. Next we check naturality. Take any morphism $f:x \to y'$ in $\mathcal C$. We need to show that
\begin{align}\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Gx @>{Gf}>> Gy\\
@V{\alpha_x}VV @VV{\alpha_y}V \\
G'x @>{G'f}>> G'y
\end{CD}\end{align}
But the Yoneda embedding reflects commutativity since it is faithful! So it is enough to apply $Y$ to the diagram and to check that the resulting diagram
\begin{align}\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal D(-,Gx) @>{\mathcal D(-,Gf)}>> \mathcal D(-,Gy)\\
@V{\cong}VV @VV{\cong}V \\
\mathcal D(-,G'x) @>{\mathcal D(-,G'f)}>> \mathcal D(-, G'y)
\end{CD}\end{align}
commutes in the functor category. But this is just the condition that the isomorphism we started with is natural in the second variable.

I hope it helps. Those arguments are all the same, you will get used to them.